# what does empty for(;;) stand for?

Tags: c#, .net

I find empty "for(;;)" statement in someone else code, and I can't figure out why it is used like this.

```
try
        {
            for (;;)
            {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an infinite loop, just like: `while (true)`